# Google Slides Apps Script retrive a shape in a page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

how to retrieve a particular shape base on the text of the shape.
example: I would like to retrieve a shape in which text starts with "Issue" and get the content of the text to input it in Google Sheets
thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the texts from the shapes in Google Slides.
- When the top of text is `Issue`, you want to retrieve the text, and want to put the retrieved texts to Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script? Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about the output situation you expect. So the following sample script puts the retrieved values to the 1st column.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. And, please set the variables and run `myFunction`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const presentationId = "###"; // Please set the presentation ID (Google Slides ID).
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const searchText = "Issue";

  // Check texts and retrieve texts from Google Slides.
  const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`);
  const slides = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId).getSlides();
  const values = slides.flatMap(slide => slide.getShapes().reduce((ar, shape) => {
    const text = shape.getText().asString().trim();
    if (regex.test(text)) ar.push([text]);
    return ar;
  }, []));

  // Put the retrieved texts to Google Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether above sample script is what you need. So when above script is not useful for your situation, in order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample Slides and the sample result you expect? By this, I would like to modify the script.

#### References:

- [getShapes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getShapes())
- [getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#getText())
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: looks very interesting. I will check and get back to you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @djchrisblue Thank you for replying. When my proposed answer was not useful for your situation, I apologize.